# How to add links to featherlight gallery afterContent

Tags: escaping, image-gallery, featherlight.js

I use the afterContent functunality to add captions to a gallery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.all-imgs').featherlightGallery({
    filter: ".img-box-img a",
    afterContent: function() {
        var caption = this.$currentTarget.find('img').attr('data-caption');
        this.$instance.find('.caption').remove();
        $('<div class="caption">').text(caption).appendTo(this.$instance.find('.featherlight-content'));
    },
    variant: "featherlight-gallery2",
  });
});
</script>
```

How do I have to escape links in the `img` elements `data-caption` attribute so that the browser renders them as links?

My usecase is to add a link to the fullsize image in the gallery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your `data-caption` attribute contains HTML, change the call to `.text(caption)` to `.html(caption)`

In your full example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.all-imgs').featherlightGallery({
    filter: ".img-box-img a",
    afterContent: function() {
        var caption = this.$currentTarget.find('img').attr('data-caption');
        this.$instance.find('.caption').remove();
        $('<div class="caption">').html(caption).appendTo(this.$instance.find('.featherlight-content'));
    },
    variant: "featherlight-gallery2",
  });
});
</script>
```